# Why is Rosemary's face never shown in the beginning of the movie?

Tags: plot-explanation, shallow-hal

In [Shallow Hal](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0256380/?ref_=ttfc_fc_tt), Hal's girlfriend Rosemary's face is not shown properly in the beginning parts of the movie.

Why so?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To de humanize her, like Hal would. Oh, she's not a person,  she's a thing. A fat ugly thing that doesn't deserve to be treated human. When Hal no longer thinks like that, when he now sees her not as an object, they show her face.